# How do I go about making a change character ontouch script?

Tags: lua, roblox

so I would like to make a script that basically calls a function whenever a block is touched, and when the block is touched, change the character of whoever touched the block only to another character model. Can anyone help?

```
local circle = script.Parent
local plr = game.Players.LocalPlayer
circle.Touched:Connect(function(part)
if part.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
    plr.Character = "O" 
end
end)
```

Comment: Please provide more details about your solution, provide code, you already have and describe your issue with more details.

Comment: code has been added.

Comment: what is your actual question? which of the necessary steps are you struggling with? you seem to know how to handle a touch event. so what is your problem? break your problem down into atomic steps and ask about the first thing you cannot solve. not about the whole idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local scripts don't run when they are a child of a part. They also won't run when there's a touch event(in this situation). It's much easier to use a script. The Character property contains a reference to a Model containing a Humanoid, body parts, scripts, and other objects required for simulating the player’s avatar in-game. The model is parented to the Workspace, but may be moved. Here is a sample code:

```
local PlayersService = game:GetService('Players')

local function Ontouch(part)
    if part.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
       local playerModelName = part.Parent.Name -- gets the name of the player model
       local player = PlayersService:FindFirstChild(playerModelName) 
       player.Character = workspace.Dummy -- write the path to the character you want
   end
end

script.Parent.Touched:Connect(Ontouch)
```

Make this a Script(not a local one) and make it the child of the part you want to touch and get the character.
For the camera to follow the newly assigned character, you need to write a script to do that.